# Ajax to autocomplete and fill dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using Spring Boot to create a web application. 
On one page, I have two input fields and two dropdowns.
When typing on the input field, it should autocomplete with names from the database. And after selection the dropdown should fill out with data for that user.
Same with the other dropdown.

My question is, if I have thousands of users or more in the database, is this the best way to achieve something like this ?
Cuz on every key a request will be fired.
Or are there more effective ways to do this ? What shows to be more efficient in databases that may grow ?

Thank you

Comment: you can use 500ms delay between each keystroke to make the backend call. This will avoid most DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

use approach: fetch data from db based on first 2 or 3 characters of user input and save data locally and then apply filter on the saved data set. Fetch again from db if the input value changes and first 2 or 3 characters doesn't match the characters from which initial data was fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling the DB per each keystroke you can query database only [when user stops typing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38543/amount-of-time-to-determine-a-user-has-stopped-typing). I usually prefer 500ms but you can experiment with this number and adjust it.

Here is some sample code to explain the idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function App() {
    $("#app").keyup(function(e) {
      this.query = e.target.value;
      this.delaySearch && clearTimeout(this.delaySearch);
      this.delaySearch = setTimeout(() => {
        // your code to get data from DB
        alert("searching for: " + this.query);
      }, 500);
    });
  }
  App();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Enter your search query here: </span><input id="app" type="text">
```